# Creating Windows live usb

Tags: windows, live-usb

How could I create Windows "live" usb in Linux?

Extra explanation: My plan is to keep the SSD containing Linux, locked and boot Windows from live USB times I need Windows. This way Linux remains safely on (faster) SSD and Windows goes to (slower) USB (this explanation about my plan was unnessary)

Comment: Welcome, windows is not very friendly with being "live". IMO your best option is just making a dual boot system.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity
Dual boot have the risk of Windows manipule Linux installation

Comment: It will, but would be just the bootloader, that you will have to restore once you installed windows. Once restored, you just choose the OS you want to boot.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Still every time I boot to Windows again, risk of manipulation (spyware injection) to Linux comes back

Comment: @EastActivist Windows is not even able to access a ext/btrfs/zfs formatted drive by default. Also the risk would still be exactly the same if you would use windows from a USB. If security is your main concern, install on LUKS encryption and setup secure boot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.